# Image/video cover entire screen in portrait aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a video header on my website that covers the entire screen. When the aspect ratio is changed (e.g. portrait), the video or image (for devices which do not support videos in the background) doesn't fill the entire screen.

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: share your source code or nobody will be able to help you, we are not wizards :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="stosto" class="header-video" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="/templates/passage/vidhead/img/elodyposter.jpg"
         class="header-video__media"         
         data-teaser="/templates/passage/vidhead/video/headerv"
         data-video-width="1172"
         data-video-height="552">
  </div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/templates/passage/vidhead/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/templates/passage/vidhead/js/script.js?v1.1"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header-video').each(function(i, elem) {
        headerVideo = new HeaderVideo({
          element: elem,
          media: '.header-video__media',
          playTrigger: '.header-video__play-trigger',
          closeTrigger: '.header-video__close-trigger'
        });
    });
  });
</script>
</div>
```